# Can I detect if specific someone joins a random voice channel (which channel did they join?)

Tags: python, discord, bots

Can I detect if specific someone (I have the id) joins a random voice channel and send my bot to that channel? I looked up a lot of forums, documentation but couldn't understand anything about how to do this.

I have an event that checks if specific someone joins a voice channel- that's ok.
but I can't send my bot to there because I don't know exactly which channel did they join.

Answer (score 0):

[on_voice_state_update(member, before, after)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update)

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after is not None and member.id == the_id:
        # check if bot is not already in the voice channel (im not sure how to) and then join it if not
```

Comment: ok first of all im dumb. which veriable is carrying the channel info right now? so I can use it to send bot to there

Comment: `after` is carrying the current channel the user is in. `after` is a https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voicechan#discord.VoiceChannel

Comment: hmm. im getting this error: `if after.voice.voice_channel is not None and member.id == "guy's id":
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice'`

Comment: Edited, that was outdated i think.